# Is color format specified in the spec for getComputedStyle?

Tags: javascript, css, colors, getcomputedstyle, cssom

I'm parsing a color string returned by `getComputedStyle` to get `R`, `G`, `B`, and `A` values from it.

So far (in Chrome and Firefox), color values always seem to come back in `rgb` or `rgba` format which is easy to parse:

```
const [, r, g, b, a] = str.replace(/\s/g, "").match(/rgba?\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?),(\d+(?:\.\d+)?),(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:,(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?\)/i);
```

I cannot, however, find any promise about color format in [any](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle) of the [specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-window-getcomputedstyle) for `getComputedStyle` listed on its [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

**Is there any guarantee of color format from `getComputedStyle`?  Or is it entirely up to browser implementation?**

I'd prefer not to have to check for HEX and HSLA values (and really whatever else is possible - I'm not entirely sure).

A quick snippet of code for testing color values in your console:

```js
console.log((str => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.backgroundColor = str;
    document.body.append(div);
    return getComputedStyle(div).backgroundColor;
})("magenta"));
```

Comment: I believe since IE6 (hex) everything has exclusively returned RGB/A, but I can't find any official documentation to back that up.

Comment: @DBS yeah, that's sort of where I am right now.  Pretty confident I could get away with it, but in search of that last 10% to help me sleep soundly at night :)

Comment: What happens with transparent? (Which is I suppose, technically, not the same as any rgba combo).

Comment: @AHaworth in FF: `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: @AHaworth I've included a code snippet for testing colors

Comment: Thanks, I am getting rgb(0, 0, 0, 0) consistently for 'transparent') (Windows 10 Edge/Chrome/FF/IE11) so the belief of getting rgb/rgba everytime is getting stronger, but I too can't find any standard defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSSOM does not state this directly, but instead [references](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#serialize-a-css-component-value) css-color-4:

> To ***serialize a CSS component value*** depends on the component, as follows:
>
> **<color>**
> If <color> is a component of a resolved value, see [CSS Color 4 §4.6 Resolving <color> Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#resolving-color-values).
>
> If <color> is a component of a computed value, see [CSS Color 4 §4.7 Serializing <color> Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#serializing-color-values).

For the purposes of `getComputedStyle()`, both of the above lines mean the same thing. Specifically, [section 4.7.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#serializing-sRGB-values) covers the majority of commonly used formats:

> #### 4.7.2. Serializing sRGB values
>
> The serialized form of the following sRGB values:
>
> - hex colors
> - `rgb()` and `rgba()` values
> - `hsl()` and `hsla()` values
> - `hwb()` values
> - named colors
>
> is derived from the computed value and thus, uses either the `rgb()` or `rgba()` form (depending on whether the alpha is exactly 1, or not), with lowercase letters for the function name.

[Section 4.7.6](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#serializing-other-colors) covers system colors (computes to lowercase), `transparent` (computes to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`) and `currentColor` (computes to lowercase `currentcolor`).

As css-color-4 introduces several new ways to specify colors, other sections exist for other formats such as [§4.7.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#resolving-lab-lch-values) for LCH values, [§4.7.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#serializing-color-function-values) for the `color()` function, and more.

This means that color values from `getComputedStyle()` are guaranteed to be in either `rgb()` or `rgba()` format, depending on the alpha value, **only** when the specified values are in any of the formats in §4.7.2. But §4.7.2 and §4.7.6 cover the vast majority of use cases in everyday CSS, so they can still be relied on. Considering the other, exotic formats aren't really supported anywhere yet, it's probably not worth testing for them until they enjoy any sort of mainstream use.