# Border color value return by window.getComputedStyle

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Given the code below,

```js
const handleClick=()=>{
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("transparent")).borderColor);
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("red")).borderColor);
}
```

```html
<div id='transparent' style='border: 2px solid transparent'/>
<div id='red' style='border: 2px solid red'/>
 


<button className="App" onclick="handleClick()">
  something
</button>
```

it output
`rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` for transparent color
`rgb(255, 0, 0)` for red color.

Will it always output in such a format for transparent and red color (e.g, not #ff0000 or red)? The reason is that I am going to do a conditional check for transparent color in my code using the following:

```
if (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("red")).borderColor == 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'){
   //do something...
}
```

Will it be a good practice or there are better way to do that?

Comment: It's by default but if you want hex color you can just pass it into a function like this and then compare: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb

Comment: Hi @m4n0, I am interested to know if that is a by default for all browsers? If yes, then my conditional checking should work well.

Comment: I just checked with Chrome and Edge. It's RGB value.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67005331/is-color-format-specified-in-the-spec-for-getcomputedstyle