# How do I check if CSS @layer is supported in CSS and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, browser-feature-detection, css-layer

So I know that [`@support`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) and [`CSS.supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports_static) can be used to check if certain features is available but I cannot in anyway make it works to detect if CSS [`@layer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@layer) is available or not. I am 100% sure my browser supports it but the following checks all return `false`:

```js
console.log(CSS.supports("@layer"))
console.log(CSS.supports("@layer a;"))
console.log(CSS.supports("@layer a {  }"))
console.log(CSS.supports("layer"))
console.log(CSS.supports("layer: 1"))
console.log(CSS.supports("layer", 1))
```

```css
p {
  color: rebeccapurple;
}

@layer type {
  .box p {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Hello, world!</p>
</div>
```

The above text shows as `purple` for me so I know `@layer` works and DevTools' CSS Layer button shows up. However all the tests are `false`.

What is the correct prompt for this check?

Comment: `@supports`, and equivalently `CSS.support()`, doesn't support checking for arbitrary CSS syntax. It can only check support for `property: value` pairs, `selector(...)`s, `font-tech(...)` and `font-format(...)`; it provides no way to check the support for at-rules.

Comment: As a workaround, you could probably implement a check using `getComputedStyle`. Would of course require the CSS to be applied already, and an element to check it on. (And I would perhaps use a different property than the color for that check - because what getComputedStyle returns for that, might be different than the actual value/keyword you specified, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67005331/1427878)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way might be to test the CSSOM for the presence of one of the Layer Rule types. So for example

```js
console.log(typeof CSSLayerBlockRule === 'function')
```

Comment: That's very clever, thanks! This does not work for CSS but I think it's easy to just put it in a separate file and if it doesn't work it doesn't work. Or just use JS to dynamically import it if it's supported.

Comment: Btw wouldn't `typeof CSSLayerBlockRule !== "undefined"` safer, _just in case_?

Comment: @LukeVo - Yes, maybe. I did say it was an example test.