# How do I test a color value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Setting a color value in Javascript is easy.

But what is the canonical color format across browsers? In other words what is the value of `window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("color")` or `window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("background-color")`? As they are strings it is hard to test for a specific color or transparency.

Is there a way in Javascript to turn these values reliably into an array `[r-value, g-value, b-value, alpha]` or any other acceptable [CSS color value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) format? Or coerce these in a comparable color format/string? Like a boolean function `Color.equal( colorString )`?

(I've spend just four days of debugging to find out that `"rgb(0 0 0/0)"` is not equal to `"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"` although semantically they are the same color.)

Comment: You should be getting back `'rgb(...)'` or `'rgba(...)'` strings - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67005331/is-color-format-specified-in-the-spec-for-getcomputedstyle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare colors in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421208/how-to-compare-colors-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @DanielBeck I believe it does. Thanks. My searches weren't thorough enough. Still this is such a PITA. It cost us days to figure out.

Comment: It is a pain.  Different browsers use various color representations, so the best you can do is draw your colors into the DOM and read everything back in the browser's preferred format using `getComputedStyle` to make comparisons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript function to convert color names to hex codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573053/javascript-function-to-convert-color-names-to-hex-codes)

Comment: @Christopher sound promising but requires the user to allow canvas. Which in LibreWolf is not on by default.

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks. that seems to be the only solution. Time for the ECMA team to get their act together. A browser does have code to convert colors in a bespoke way so it would be easy to have a browser canonicalize a color in much the same way. Not to a string but to an object. that can be compared